# Microsoft authorization with new tab

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, oauth-2.0

I need to implement login functionality with Microsoft via a new tab.

Currently our login process works with Microsoft in a  way which is not really suited for our needs. The  user clicks a login button, gets redirected to the Microsoft sign in page, enters his information and gets redirected back to our login page. This all happens on the same tab. In the code bellow is an example of this:

```
authenticateOffice(finallyCallback?: () => void): void {
    finallyCallback = finallyCallback || (() => {
    });

    let currentUrl = location.href;
    this.redirectLocationUrl = currentUrl.substr(0, currentUrl.indexOf('#'));
    let url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/".concat(this.office365Domain, "/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=", this.clientId,
        "&response_type=id_token&redirect_uri=", this.redirectLocationUrl, "&response_mode=fragment&scope=openid profile&state=12345&nonce=678910");

     window.location.href = url;
}
```

Pretty straightforward and nothing too complex.

What we need to do in layman's terms is:
1. Open a new tab when clicking the login button
2. User enters his information on the Microsoft login page
3. When authorized, tab is automatically closed
4. Our login page then receives the "id_token" from Microsoft from oauth2 and with this I do the rest of my login logic

```
else if (!StringHelper.isNullOrEmpty(window.location.hash) && window.location.hash.startsWith('#id_token')) {
    let response = window.location.hash;
    this._office365Service.getOfficeId(response)
        .subscribe((result: string) => {
                let key = result;
                if (key) {
                    this._loginService.processOfficeIdResult(key);
                } else {
                    abp.message.warn(this._localizationService.localize('Office365User', this.localizationSourceName));
                }                  
            });
}
```

My question is this:
How can we regain or rather take control of this "new" tab and do something with it?
How can we know when authorization is complete?If it fails or is successful?

In my previous research all i could come by was the callback approach but how can you send a function to a new tab which knows when to close the tab?And how can you receive authorization information when the user is successfully authenticated?

```
var win = window.open("window.html");
```

And then what? You write a function which calls itself every second and checks for input?
(just throwing ideas here)

Comment: Can use postMessage API or storage events to communicate between the two windows. Use a very minimal page for the redirect and put script in that oage to tell opening page of success. Will know success when the redirect gets loaded and has the proper params in url

Comment: In this situation is better to open a popup window.

Comment: We will use a popup window. It's best if we dont over complicate things if it's not needed.